# Why isn't my App Script sending requests to my server when a user edits a cell on Google Sheets?

Tags: http, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, localhost

I have an App script for Google Sheet file. And when ever a user edit a cell I send a request to my server sid that runs on localhost:3000. the problem is I don't receive a request when the user edit any cell.

App Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

   const url = "http://localhost:3000/user/edit";
  const options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  
}
```

My server side:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
const { urlencoded } = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
require("dotenv").config();
const User = require("./Models/user");



app.use(urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});





app.post("/user/edit", (req,res) => {
  console.log("Hello");
})


//db connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Could not connect to the database", error);
    process.exit();
  });


require("./Router/userRoute")(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried different codes but, I think the problem isn't in my code.

Comment: Google Apps Script is run on the server side. So, unfortunately, the request to your localhost cannot be directly run. And also, in the current stage, the simple trigger of OnEdit cannot use UrlFetchApp. Please be careful about this.

Comment: So I need to deploy my backend to a host server like heroku, Right ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your reply, I think that it's yes.

Comment: You could try using an installable onEdit trigger.  Name it something other than onEdit and you can create it in the trigger section of the editor.  If there is not a internet connection between the google server and the destination server then even this will not work.

Comment: I've done what you said about (installable onEdit trigger) i used myOnEdit function and didn't work as well. I've deployd my backend to Vercel and I still not getting any request.